# Direct url not working in vuejs but router push works

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vue-router

When i load the component `localhost:8080/scan` using `this.$router.push()`, url loads with the component But when i do `npm run build` and then `http-server dist/`, the url `localhost:8080/scan` doesn't work, gives a 404.
Any idea why it works in dev and not after build.
I did check online and found it was a nginx issue but i tried adding `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;` as per this doc: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html but nothing seems to work. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post your complete code to the question, or a github repository. Otherwise it's hard to guess what's your issue.

If I had to guess - your `http-server` can't find `scan.html` because it doesn't exist. You have a few options:

- Use `hash mode` which won't require the `/scan` url and rely on `/index.html#scan` instead.
- Use a node-js server with defined routes that go to your html page. Or just send all of them to the same page. Here's an example https://github.com/ubershmekel/redditp/blob/1e9a659bcc34fa2f2dc28deb552b6702a1173cc1/app.js#L12
- Use Nuxt or do something like Nuxt does - build all the html files so you can still use a static server like `http-server`. See https://nuxtjs.org/guide#static-generated-pre-rendering- For example you can copy your `index.html` to `scan.html` manually.